# Where to Use WCF in a Big Web Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

We are planning to develop a big application in web, our current plan is to create a WCF service for each class in the Business layer. Is this effective? I want to know where can we use WCF in a big web application and main advantages of using it

we have these projects

```
1) MVC3 with Razor that handles UI 

2) Class Library Project that communicate with Database

3) WCF Project
```

Method we using

```
1)Creates UI and Model  in MVC 

2)Makes dll that communicate with UI (eg:Save function/Update function) using ClassLibrary Project

3)The Class Library Created is Added (Added to Bin) in WCF Project 

4) Builds the WCF and Host It in Server

5) The Hosted Service is Used in MVC Project for Communication with DB
```

Our Technical lead is saying it is light weight and more secure but i am wondering why he is saying to use `WCF` for whole appication

Comment: Why do you need to use WCF at all?

Comment: @KMan your comment makes it sound as if you have more to say.  Do you have a better alternative than WCF?

Comment: @KMan this is big project in web, lot of transactions are there, any advantage in using WCF

Answer (score 2):

First ask this question, why do you need a service layer, when it could be achieved by a separate application. If you want to achieve this for just loose coupling, then it does not makes sense.

In my opinion, the service layer would be useful for exposing your data (dal-layer) and not Business Layer. For example take twitter. Twitter exposes it data over Web Services. What you do with the data is completely your interpretation. The data could be consumed by many application over HTTP. So your client could be remotely situated and need not to be on the same server as your application. The business layer could change based upon interpretation of data. The consumer, then need to worry about latest changes and including latest DLL. It will just consume the webservice. Also mocking your service would be pretty easy and you could write your NUnits tests very easy on your Business layer then. I would also recommend you to have a look at **ASP.Net Web API**, which provides restful way of exposing your services and data(with inbuilt capablity of exposing it as JSON). The RestFull service has many advantages over WCF, like you then need not to worry about WSDL and etc. The interface always remains same. Consuming a RestFul service is very easy.

As again with the twitter example. The clients consuming twitter api's are not situated on same server. So it makes sense to expose it over HTTP.
But if you do not have such a requirement(Client is not remotely situated), then exposing your data over web services does not make sense. Then a separate application will give you loose coupling and that should be good enough for you. Also exposing data on HTTP will have some performance impact too.

**UPDATE 2**

I understand the scenario you are trying to implement and I think its perfectly allright. By light weight he means, from your WCF service he would do interaction with Database and then send light weight DTO's for each action and controller as per requirement. So basically your WCF would do nothing but invoke methods from your class library, would fetch some Business Object and Convert it back to DTO(as required by your action to render UI) and send it to Controller.

Also make sure, you use Dependency Injection for your Services, so that you could write NUnit tests for your controller with mock data and hence no requirement of Database for running your NUnits

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to have the service layer be a completely independent application that can be consumed by many applications.  It makes projects, especially large ones, much easier to scale, than if you were to create your service layer inside a single web application.

Comment: we are doing like that but the problem is services are created for each class then there will be 1000's of services

Comment: Why there would 1000 services. Read my post. You should expose Data over service and not your BL classes.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatly to tell you. Using WCF is less effective. The main purpose to use WCF it to let your data can be accessed with any client application. not just web application. you may also have a Silverlight or winform. WCF has nothing to do with "A BIG" web app.